# Адресация матрицы

Tags: c

Скажите пожалуйста где я напутала в адресации с matr?

(код поправлен)

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void scan_matr(int ***matr, int *n){
    printf("Введите порядок матрицы:"); scanf("%i", n);
    printf("\nВведите матрицу:\n");
    matr = (int**)malloc(*n * sizeof(int*));

    for (int i = 0; i < *n; ++i) {
        matr[i] = (int*)malloc((*n+1) * sizeof(int));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < *n; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < *n+1; ++j) {
            scanf("%i",&(matr[i][j]));
        }
        puts("");
    }
}

int* solveGauss(int **matr, int *n) {
    int *vectors;
    vectors = malloc(*n * sizeof(int));
    for (int k = 1; k < *n; ++k) {
        for (int j = k; j < *n; ++j) {
            int a = matr[j][k-1];
            int b = matr[k-1][k-1];
            int m = a/b;
            for (int i = 0; i < *n+1; ++i) {
                matr[j][i] = matr[j][i] - m*matr[k-1][i];
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = *n-1; i >= 0 ; --i) {
        vectors[i] = matr[i][*n]/matr[i][i];
        for (int c = n-1; c > i; --c) {
            vectors[i] = vectors[i] - matr[i][c] * vectors[c] / matr[i][i];
        }
    }

    return vectors;
}

int main()
{
    int **matr, n;

    scan_matr(matr,&n);

    int *vectors = solveGauss(&matr,&n);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Совет: Не используйте для матриц массивы указателей на массивы. Гораздо проще выделить одномерный массив размера `w * h`, а потом вместо `mat[x][y]` делать `mat[x + y*w]`.

Comment: В цикле `for (int c = 0; c > i; --c) { vectors[i] = vectors[i] - matr[i][c] * vectors[c] / matr[i][i];}` скорее всего начальное число не должно быть нулём.

Comment: На этот код компилятор вам выдал ворох диагностических сообщений, указывающих вам на ваши ошибки. Вы решили их просто проигнорировать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `scan_matr` и `solveGauss` вы передаёте `&matr == int ***` т.е. адрес матрицы. А принимаете как аргумент матрицу. `int **`

```
int ** scan_matr( int *n){
  printf("Введите порядок матрицы:"); scanf("%i", n);
  printf("\nВведите матрицу:\n");
  int **matr = (int**)malloc(*n * sizeof(int*));
  for (int i = 0; i < *n; ++i) {
    matr[i] = (int*)malloc((*n+1) * sizeof(int));    }
  for (int i = 0; i < *n; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < *n+1; ++j) {
        scanf("%i",&(matr[i][j]));        }
    puts("");    } 
return matr;}

int* solveGauss(int **matr, int *n) {
    int *vectors;
    vectors = malloc(*n * sizeof(int));
    for (int k = 1; k < *n; ++k) {
        for (int j = k; j < *n; ++j) {
            int a = matr[j][k-1];
            int b = matr[k-1][k-1];
            int m = a/b;
            for (int i = 0; i < *n+1; ++i) {
                matr[j][i] = matr[j][i] - m*matr[k-1][i];  } } }
    for (int i = *n-1; i >= 0 ; --i) {
        vectors[i] = matr[i][*n]/matr[i][i];
        for (int c = 0; c > i; --c) {
            vectors[i] = vectors[i] - matr[i][c] * vectors[c] / matr[i][i];        }    }

    return vectors;}


int main(){
    int  n;
    int * * matr = scan_matr(&n);
    int *vectors = solveGauss(matr,&n);
    return 0; }
```

Comment: Наоборот нужно аргумент `int ***` в `scan_matr`. И передавать адрес `matr`. В `sloveGauss` можно оставить.

Comment: Ну вот я вроде исправила, как вы сказали, но теперь опять на int b = matr[k-1][k-1] вылетает ;*(

Comment: ООО, спасибо, всё отлично, только вы не подскажите подаскажите где в википедиевском алгоритме ошибка https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fd/Gauss.png? У меня при таких `3
1 -2 1 0
2 2 -1 3
4 -1 1 5` данных деление на ноль происходит в обратном ходе `vectors[i] = matr[i][*n]/matr[i][i];`

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = n-1; i >= 0 ; --i) {
    vectors[i] = matr[i][*n]/matr[i][i];
```

Вы уж выбирайте что-то одно, а то у вас цикл со счетчиком от `n-1`, а матрица - с `*n` :)

Ну, вы поняли? Если уж передаете адрес - то не забывайте разыменовывать...

И еще - если выделяете память для `N` элементов, то обращение к `N`-ому элементу - это таки выход за границы массива...

Это так, навскидку. Что бросается в глаза. Серьезнее не копал, так что вряд ли это все неприятности... Одного `int m = a/b;` за глаза хватает, чтоб не работало...